# How is it to debug the data() call in D3?

Tags: javascript, debugging, d3.js

I am triying with this example code but it is not correct:

```
var aaa = ["a","b","c"];
d3.selectAll(".none").data(aaa).enter().call(function(d) {console.log(d);});
```

or

```
var aaa = ["a","b","c"];
d3.selectAll("html").data(aaa).enter().call(function(d) {console.log(d);});
```

Comment: can you paste your complete code? I think this is not correct code

Comment: Yes, I know those codes are incorrect. How I do for correct this code? That is the question :) .

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

D3 allows you to bind arbitrary data to a Document Object Model (DOM), and then apply data-driven transformations to the document.

You need to initiate the data join by defining the selection to which we will join data with :

```
var bar = chart.selectAll("div");
```

After, you need to join the data (defined previously) to the selection using selection.data.

```
var barUpdate = bar.data(data);
```

But the selection is empty, so you need instantiate these missing elements by appending to the enter selection.

```
var barEnter = barUpdate.enter().append("div");
```

So you will create one DOM object per data. You can set any attribute you want (class,id,...) of the associated data value, d.

```
barEnter.attr("class", function(d) { return d * 10 + "px"; });
```

Concerning your question, you could debug your data when you create each object for each data like this :

```
var Viz = d3.select(".myViz")
            .selectAll("div")
            .data(aaa)
            .enter().append("div")
            .attr("class", function(d) { console.log(d); });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It is near but it still doesn't show the console.log. (I have checked in my firefox with firebug).
`var aaa = ["a","b","c"];
undefined
var Viz = d3.select(".myViz").selectAll("div").data(aaa).enter().append("div").attr("class", function(d) { console.log(d); });
undefined`

Comment: I made a fiddle for you. [FiddleLink](https://jsfiddle.net/HugoLasticot/am9ze3kn/)

Your data have the wrong format. You need to ceate an array of object.

Answer (score 5):

Although the answer from @HugoLasticot is very helpful and explanatory, one might add that you can use the construct `call()` to run arbitrary functions.

```
d3node
  .select(".selector")
  .call((d) => console.log(d))
```

This might help you when debugging.

[Here](http://objjob.phrogz.net/d3/methods) is the complete list of d3 functions.